# In R, how do I recode survey for LCA so first response is 1, not 0? The range is now 0-4

Tags: r

I am dealing with two likert type survey. The response options both start with 0. In R, poLCA will not run unless I can recode it so it begins with 1, not 0.
I have tried ifelse, mutate, recode.

Comment: Change all you responses to response + 1.  How you do that is dependent on how the response data is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you change the value so it is one higher? thus starting with 1 instead of 0:

```
your.data %<>% mutate( value = value + 1 )
```